# How to use regular expression to search two variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Hello and thank you for your help in advance.  I have two fields that I'm pulling down.  One contains a list of states in this format NY, MO, GA etc.  This field is set up in a variable called states.  I have another variable called restricted which gets pulled down also.  Restricted will only have one state abbreviation in it.  So NY.  What I want to do is search the states variable with the restricted variable and return a boolean value.

```
var states = "NY, MO, GA, IL";
var restricted = "NY";

var search = new RegExp(restricted);
var res = search.test(states);
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: so what is the problem or question? Code shown works fine

Comment: `"NY, MO, GA, IL".contains("NY") === true`

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any need for a regular expression here. Just search the states string for the restricted value.

`var found = states.indexOf(restricted) >= 0;`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf